# Simple.OData.Client Inheritance Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata, simple.odata, simple.odata.client

I am currently having an issue when using [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client) to retrieve an object.

Here's the call, using an instance of `ODataClient`

```
RecurringObjectView model = await client.For<RecurringObjectView>("RecurringObjects")
                                        .Key(id)
                                        .Expand(r => r.RecurrenceSetting)
                                        .FindEntryAsync();
```

I'm able to trace the data coming from the API, and all is well. Below is an extract of the Json being return by the server.

```
{
    "RecurrenceSetting": {
        "@odata.type":"#Namespace.Of.The.DailyRecurrenceSettingView",
        "Id":16
        // more settings...
     }
     // more values...
}
```

The issue is that the `RecurrenceSetting` object is abstract, and in turn is giving the following error...

> **Unable to create an instance of type `RecurrenceSettingView` that does
>   not have a default constructor.**

For reference purposes, here are extracts of the class definitions...

```
public class RecurringObjectView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual RecurrenceSettingView RecurrenceSetting { get; set; }

    // loads more properties...
}


public abstract class RecurrenceSettingView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // common recurrence setting properties...
}

public class DailyRecurrenceSettingView :
    RecurrenceSettingView
{
    // daily specific settings...
}
```

Comment: So which type should the client instantiate when deserializing a `RecurrenceSettingView` and how should it know that?

Comment: @CodeCaster I've edited the question and added some of the Json that is being returned by the server. The "@odata.type":"#Namespace.Of.The.DailyRecurrenceSettingView", should be sufficient to deserialize the correct concret object.

Comment: You're right. That is, if the client library supports it. It should use `@odata.type` to feed hints to the serializer.

Comment: @CodeCaster Agreed! Either I'm missing something or it doesn't in fact support it... which is kinda a pain!